# Multiple modals on webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem with modals. I want to make many modals for example 2 modals. First modal works correctly but second isn't opening.

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-name: animatetop;
    animation-duration: 0.4s
}

/* Add Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0} 
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

@keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: white;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    color: white;
}

.modal-body {padding: 2px 16px;}

.modal-footer {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    color: white;
}

.video-container {
    position:relative;
    padding-bottom:56.25%;
    padding-top:30px;
    height:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.video-container iframe, .video-container object, .video-container embed {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e4/Small-city-symbol.svg/348px-Small-city-symbol.svg.png" id="myBtn" class="image fit" alt="" />
 <div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <h2>Header</h2>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body">
   <br />
   <br />
   <div class="video-container"><iframe width="100" height="100" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/LRblJyq_4Ko?rel=0?ecver=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a0/Circle_-_black_simple.svg/2000px-Circle_-_black_simple.svg.png" id="myBtn" class="image fit" alt="" />
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <span class="close">&times;</span>
                <h2>Header</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            <br />
            <br />
            <div class="video-container"><iframe width="100" height="100" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/LRblJyq_4Ko?rel=0?ecver=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I want to make many modals working correctly! Look, second modal doesn't open. Any solutions? Please easy solutions, I don't want to change much my code.

Comment: IDs **must** be **unique**. Target a class rather than and ID if you want to target multiple objects.

Comment: I don't understand... Can you repair my code? I'm beginner at programming

Comment: You cannot use 2 identical `id="myModal"` or two identical `id="MyBtn"` attributes. Each one needs to be **unique**.

Comment: That means that I must define new functions to js file?

Comment: @OlivierPiasecki yes, you're going to have to rewrite a fair amount of that javascript and update your HTML. You can always just use bootstrap or a modal plugin http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals